Navigate to a URL Addressable LWC from a Visualforce page
We are using a third party package on a custom Visualforce page - it's not possible to use it on an LWC due to security settings. Everything on the Visualforce side is working as intended, however when we try to navigate back directly to a url addressable LWC - we are running into issues.
 var save = function (templateName, content) {
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.utilityClass.initialTemplateCreation}', content, 
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status){
                        //Let's do the redirect to the LWC now
                        // Redirect to the Lightning App page that contains the LWC
                        window.location.href = '/lightning/cmp/c__eventCommApp?c__eventId=${eventId}';
                    }
                },
                {escape: true}
                )
            
        };
    

So the window re-loading is working correctly - however we're getting an embedded window which is occurring and the VF page is behaving as it's own window. An example is below:

I feel like I'm missing a fairly obvious solution - but I don't do a lot of work with Visualforce pages these days so I'm probably missing a fairly basic approach.

The old-school VF solution would be to use an apex controller/extension that returns a PageReference object for the page you want to navigate to.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_system_pagereference.htm
If you want to call an apex method from javascript you can use apex:actionFunction
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm
(both links also have code samples that explain how to use them)
Hopefully this will behave better, it's hard to say how well VF was integrated into LEX (not surprised the window property has special behaviour).
Maybe somebody will have a more "updated" solution specifically for the VF/LEX combo, but the solution above was how we used to do it in VF before LEX UI was rolled out, so hopefully it still works correctly.

Thank you for the answer - unfortunately neither approach is giving me a different experience. I'm still getting the strange window within a window. I'll try something different with the DOM perhaps or set up a new tab maybe.

Looks like salesforce really didn't integrate VF into LEX in the best way  If you find a solution, please let us know!
